# phpMyAdmin Shows 404 Not Found nginx ubuntu 18.04 with asp.net

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, nginx, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin Shows 404 Not Found
http://ip_host/phpmyadmin

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 server running a LEMP (Linux, Nginx, MySQL and PHP)
I created asp.net application and change config file.
Now phpMyAdmin Shows 404 Not Found
http://ip_host/phpmyadmin

```
server {

    server_name myhost.ru  www.myhost.ru;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
listen 443 ssl; 
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.ru/fullchain.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.ru/privkey.pem; 
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 


}
server {
if ($host = www.myhost.ru) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} 


if ($host = myhost.ru) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} 


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name myhost.ru  www.myhost.ru;
return 404; 
}
```

When I type myhost/phpmyadmin, it shows a 404 Not Found error. How can I fix this? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: How about [*not* installing phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin) and using readily available MYSQL GUI clients? (MySQL Workbench, Sequel Pro, etc. etc. support much more features, secure and easier to install and configure, and also more secure)

Comment: It's a good idea. But this is my first steps on database apps and phpmyadmin installed by default and i want to understand why i have a problem. And if i didn't fix it, i will install MYSQL Workbench.